# How to configure OIDC token authentication (I am using firebase) using aws-amplify library?

Tags: firebase-authentication, openid-connect, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am using aws-amplify javascript library for query, mutations etc on AWS Appsync API. I am using OpenId Connect as the default authorization mode and have configured Firebase as the IdentityProvider (IdP). So, basically I want to add the firebaseToken to amplify-configuration. How do we proceed?
NOTE: I have solutions that use appsync-js sdk to do this. But, I wish to use the aws-amplify library itself.
Let me know if it is possible at all.